# Is it possible to have two NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription strings?

Tags: ios, location-services

I have two features in my app that needs to use GPS location. One uses your location to pull in relevant data based on your area, and one uses it to place a pin on a map at your current location.

I don't want to use the same description for both features but I can't find anywhere that explains how use different strings. Is it even possible to change the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription based on what feature is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't have two separate messages. The user will only ever see the message one time - the first time the app tries to access location services. Once the user agrees or denies, the message will never be seen again (unless the user resets all privacy settings on the device).

Since the user will end up using locations services for both features of your app, in no particular order, and since they will only see the message once, you simply need to use a more generic reason message.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

I would recommend that you consolidate the two descriptions, and disregard the "places pin on the map" use case. The important thing you are doing for your users is "getting relevant data based on your area," so tailor your description around that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't answer my question. I'm looking to find out if it is even possible to use different descriptions based on what feature is opened. I would like to consolidate the descriptions only if it's my only option.